# Cannot find crtn.o, linking 32 bit code on 64 bit system

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, nasm, ld

I'm attempting to assemble some 32-bit code using NASM and GCC on a 64-bit system. I use the following two commands

```
nasm -f elf32 -g -F stabs coc.asm
gcc -m32 -o coc coc.o
```

NASM appears to do fine, but LD complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and I checked and I'm pretty sure libc is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling problems: cannot find crt1.o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not assembling, but linking an executable, which needs OS startup files.

It seems you don't have `gcc-*-multilib` installed, which contains the necessary files: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/gcc-4.6-multilib/filelist

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `gcc-multilib` to get the proper 32-Bit lib

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on ubuntu 11.10. [See my question on SO about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130175/why-can-i-not-build-a-lower-version-compiler). What helped for me, was linking the `crt*.o` to `/lib/`. After that I never had other problems with this issue. A bit more of a cludge, but for me it solved the problems.

Comment: exactly what do you mean by "linking the crt*.o to /lib/" ?