# 32 bit standard C library on 64 bit machine

Tags: c, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I am using ubuntu 12.04 on 64 bit machine, I have this simple C code:

```
 int b = 20;
 int c = 10;

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      c = 50;
 }
```

I was trying make it compatible with any IA32 machine by compiling it like this:

```
 unix> gcc -m32 code.c
```

And got these errors:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I understand, this is happening because I'm missing 32 bit standard C library, so linker cannot link my code against standard C library.

How can I obtain the needed 32 standard C on my 64 bit machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find crtn.o, linking 32 bit code on 64 bit system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807581/cannot-find-crtn-o-linking-32-bit-code-on-64-bit-system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
  apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Also, you should compile/link with -m32:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -m32 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing into right direction, sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386

Comment: @Rustam Issabekov - cool.  Thanx for posting back the complete solution for you!

Comment: what should I install on a machine with yum ? It says there isn't any anything called `ia32-libs`

Comment: There is no direct equivalent of ia32-libs for Centos/Fedora/etc.  You need to install the appropriate *.686 package(s).  EXAMPLE: `yum install compat-libstdc++-296.i686`.  Here are more details: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/9556/how-do-i-install-32bit-libraries-on-a-64-bit-fedora/

Comment: I got  a linker error after this, and had to `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8-multilib` as well